# Is it possible to swap from ValueChanges to (blur) in order to make a request?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I´m asking this because I started taking some basic angular lessons and I´m using some filters at the moment that send the request to firebase while I´m typing with ValueChanges:

This is the imput that is used to search:

```
<input
  type="search"
  placeholder="Teclee un proveedor..."
  [formControl]="campoBusqueda"
  />
```

And this is the code I have in `ngOnInit()` to work with it:

```
this.campoBusqueda = new FormControl();
this.campoBusqueda.valueChanges.subscribe(term => {
  this.busqueda = term;
  this.cargando = true;
  if (this.busqueda.length !== 0) {
    this.proveedoresService
      .getProveedoresSearch(this.busqueda)
      .subscribe(proveedores => {
        this.proveedores = [];
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const id$ in proveedores) {
          const p = proveedores[id$];
          p.id$ = id$;
          this.proveedores.push(proveedores[id$]);
        }
        if (this.proveedores.length < 1 && this.busqueda.length >= 1) {
          this.noresultados = true;
          this.proveedoresService
            .getProveedores()
            .subscribe( proveedores => {
              this.proveedores = [];
              // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
              for (const id$ in proveedores) {
                const p = proveedores[id$];
                p.id$ = id$;
                this.proveedores.push(proveedores[id$]);
              }
            });
        } else {
          this.noresultados = false;
        }
      });
    this.cargando = false;
    this.resultados = true;
  } else {
    this.proveedores = [];
    this.cargando = false;
    this.resultados = false;
  }
});
```

Now what I´d like to know is if it would be possible to use (blur):

```
    <input
    type="search"
    placeholder="Teclee un proveedor..."
    [formControl]="campoBusqueda"
    (blur)="myNewSearchMethod()"
    />
```

To make the request after the user gets the focus out of the input instead of making it everytime the user types something in the input.

My `myNewSearchMethod()` that I´m using right know is :

```
    myNewSearchMethod() {
    this.campoBusqueda = new FormControl();
    this.busqueda = this.campoBusqueda.value;
    this.cargando = true;
    if (this.busqueda.length !== 0) {
        this.proveedoresService
          .getProveedoresSearch(this.busqueda)
          .subscribe(proveedores => {
            this.proveedores = [];
            // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
            for (const id$ in proveedores) {
              const p = proveedores[id$];
              p.id$ = id$;
              this.proveedores.push(proveedores[id$]);
            }
            if (this.proveedores.length < 1 && this.busqueda.length >= 1) {
              this.noresultados = true;
              this.proveedoresService
                .getProveedores()
                .subscribe( proveedores => {
                  this.proveedores = [];
                  // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
                  for (const id$ in proveedores) {
                    const p = proveedores[id$];
                    p.id$ = id$;
                    this.proveedores.push(proveedores[id$]);
                  }
                });
            } else {
              this.noresultados = false;
            }
          });
        this.cargando = false;
        this.resultados = true;
      } else {
        this.proveedores = [];
        this.cargando = false;
        this.resultados = false;
      };
  }
```

The problem right now is that when I´m using (blur) the value of the input disapears after tabbing or clicking out of the input giving a null value when it reached the first if `if (this.busqueda.length !== 0) {` giving the next stacktrace in console:

```
ProveedoresComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at ProveedoresComponent.push../src/app/proveedores/proveedores/proveedores.component.ts.ProveedoresComponent.myNewSearchMethod (proveedores.component.ts:170)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ProveedoresComponent.html:9)
at handleEvent (core.js:23097)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24167)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23894)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:20546)
at core.js:20993
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work for you?

Comment: Well sure why not? Does it not working?

Comment: i´ve tried creating the new method and it works the first time (blur) pops out but after that if i try to search again it searchs while i´m typing due to the ValueChanges

Comment: @arturo just remove your valueChanges subscribe and just call function on `(blur)`

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari I´ve tried getting rid of my valueChanges.subscribe() by getting the value of this.busqueda = campoBusqueda.value but if I do that it pops an error when it tries to get the length of busqueda

Comment: can you create Stackblitz ?

Comment: i dont really know how to do it, but the problem i have know is that after tabbing or clicking out of the input the text of the input disapears and due to that when it reaches busqueda.length the value is null

Comment: @arturo i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **updateOn** FormHooks

> Reports the update strategy of the AbstractControl (meaning the event
>   on which the control updates itself). Possible values: 'change' |
>   'blur' | 'submit' Default value: 'change

**component.ts**

```
 campoBusqueda = new FormControl('',{
    updateOn:'blur'
  });
```

Example::https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5e7qd2

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will definitely work for you. You just have to remove `vlaueChanges` subscription from .ts and just call your search function like this

in your .ts file just keep this code

```
searchForm : FormGroup;
this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
  searchField : new FormControl('')
})

myNewSearchMethod(){
  // This condition will check if there is some value in `searchField` or not
 if(this.searchForm.get('searchField ').value){
  // call your search function here
  }
}

<input
type="search"
placeholder="Teclee un proveedor..."
[formControl]="campoBusqueda"
(blur)="myNewSearchMethod()"
/>
```

Comment: going to try this option, I´ll come back with fresh news

Comment: Ok , accept this answer if this solution will work for you

Comment: Ok, now I dont lose the value of the input but it doesnt get into the condition of the if, i´m guessing that searchField is my campoBusqueda

Comment: just declare a whole form like i declared and make a searchField control inside that form and bind that form's control to your input. I gave you full example

Comment: You can just comment your this declaration `this.campoBusqueda = new FormControl();` and replace that with my form declaration and do the stuff like i did in my answer

Comment: I couldnt make it work this way, the other solution worked and it´s solved, i give you and upvote for the help and attention after all :)